# Вопрос по конфигурации webpack

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

В свое время набросал простенький конфиг для домашнего проекта. В нем использовал `webpack-dev-server`. Также в этом же конфиге у меня генерируется стартовый html, в который я подгружаю App ReactJs. Теперь хочу сделать по-другому. Есть проект на `php` локально, в котором есть уже готовый `twig`. И хотелось бы не генерировать webpack'ом `index.html`, а задействовать этот `twig` в работе. Можно ли это как-то сделать? Если да то подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: А зачем он вам? Для разработки подключайте скрипты и стили как и раньше, с помощью генерации html файла, а на продакшене уже подключайте собранные файлы в twig.

Comment: то есть не использовать этот твиг при разработке, конфиг оставить как есть с девсервером?в твиге просто указать пути на js и css бандлы?

Comment: Если у вас SPA, работающие через API с бэком, то да. Так проще и удобнее.

Comment: спасибо,так и сделал, без дев сервера.просто бандлы к твигу подключил и все